# Is "making a racket" some part of music?

Tags: terminology

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=573) (a video link with a time stamp)

> while I'm playing
>   me drums in here making a **racket**

I am aware that playing drums looks like this

[image]

Is "making a racket" some part of it?

Comment: "Making a racket" means "making a din". It is jocular BrE. So is the 'me' for 'my' in "I'm playing me drums." "I'll just get me coat", "Where's me 'at?" etc.

Comment: A 'din' is a loud noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general usage, the phrase "making a racket" is offensive.  As noted by the Cambridge Dictionary (see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/racket), a "racket" is:

> an unpleasant loud continuous noise:
>
> "They were making such a racket outside that I couldn't get to sleep."

In the specific example you have chosen, the person making the music seems to be using the term in one of two ways.

- First, he may be using the term somewhat **ironically** - e.g. knowing that his conservative neighbours would hate his drum-playing and would consider it to be an unpleasant "racket", he wishes to proudly "own" the noise and therefore "owns" the insult!  This is why he self-describes the music as a "racket"!
- Second, he may be using it factually - e.g. to note that although he is making a very loud noise, his excellent sound-proofing means that he cannot be heard by his neighbours.

Note also that the author of these words intentionally uses "bad English" to convey that he's a rough character, whose music is also rough.

- "Bad" English: "while I'm playing **me** drums in here ..."
- "Good" English: "While I'm playing **my** drums in here, ...."

Please note that I have not had time to watch the video in full, which means that my reply may need to be amended after watching it.

Comment: When I hear rap 'music' coming out of automobiles I think "God, what a racket".

Comment: Consider the video is to show how to soundproof, which indicates that he did a work to prevent his music from disturbing his neighbors. So, is it possible that guy uses "racket" to convey more joking than ironic?

Comment: @zghqh - Ah, I had not caught that additional information about sound-proofing, because (I'm sorry!) I had not watched the video all the way through.  If the video is about sound-proofing, then when he says he is "making a racket" he's not being ironic or even joking: he is just saying that he is making "a very loud noise" which cannot be heard by his neighbours.